# How can I display if the password doesn't match the one in the database?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I'm new to react and node and I can't find a way to display when the password/email is different from the one in the Mongo database.

Also, when I enter the wrong credentials it gives me this error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'email')

How can I solve that?

**This is the homepage**

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react'
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom'
const axios = require('axios')


const Home = () => {

let navigate = useNavigate()
const [isRegistered, setIsRegistered] = useState(false)
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    name: "",
    email: "",
    password: ""
})

// save the data of each input in the state
const handleChange = (e) => {
  setFormData({
    ...formData,
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value
  })
}

//on submit, send the data to the server with axios
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  axios.post(`http://localhost:8000/${isRegistered ? "signup" : "login"}` , {formData})
  .then((res) => {
    const success = res.status === 200
    if (success && isRegistered){
       navigate('/onboarding')
     } 
    if (success && !isRegistered) {
      navigate ('/dashboard')
      console.log(res)
    } else {
      console.log("password is wrong")
    }
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
}

  return (
    <div className='home'>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            {isRegistered &&<input onChange={handleChange} type="text" name='name' placeholder='name' required/>}
            <input onChange={handleChange} type="email" name="email" placeholder='email' required/>                
            <input onChange={handleChange} type="password" name='password' placeholder='password' required/>
            <input type="submit"/>
        </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

**This is the server**:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const cors = require('cors')
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "AAA"

app.use(cors())
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json())


app.post('/signup', function (req, res) {
    let data = req.body.formData
    res.send("success")

    MongoClient.connect(url, (err, db) =>{
        if (err) throw err;
        const database = db.db("data");
        database.collection("utenti").insertOne(data, function(err, res) {
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log(res)
            db.close()
        });
    });
})

app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    const client = new MongoClient(url)
    const data = req.body.formData
    

    try{
        await client.connect()
        const database = client.db("data")
        const collection = database.collection("utenti")   
    
        const result = await collection.findOne({email: data.email, password: data.password})

        if (result.email && result.password){
            res.status(200).send("Success")
        } else {
            res.status(400).send("Invalid credentials")
        }

    } catch(err){console.log(err)}
})

app.listen(8000)
```

Comment: In the catch method instead of logging error, you can define error state and set that error state in the catch method. Display error state below the form.

Answer (score 0):

For "TypeError" Send JSON Data properly in axios request like this

```
axios.post(`http://localhost:8000/${isRegistered ? "signup" : "login"}` , {
formData: formData
})
```